# Unable to justify content in navigation to next to the brand name in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to place my navigation menu next to my brand name, using Bootstrap.

Here's my code:

```
<nav class="navbar-expand">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://example.com" target="_blank">Brand</a>
  <nav class="nav justify-content-start">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">FAQ</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Download</a>
  </nav>
</nav>
```

I'm using `navbar-expand` as it forces horizontal navbars, even on mobile, but it places the content under the brand name, which is not what I want. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You could try adding this CSS rule: `nav.nav.justify-content-start { float: right; }`

Comment: @CalebH. Tried that, it just made the nav bar content go to the top right of the page.

Comment: Well, I thought that was what you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this in your css. hope this is what you are looking for. thanks

```
.navbar-expand{
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;}
```